# Why is numpy.isrealobj('a string') True?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I noticed that numpy.isrealobj returns True for strings or booleans while numpy.iscomplexobj returns False (even if the string could represent a complex number).

numpy.isreal returns False for a string (even if the string could represent a real number) but True for a boolean.

However numpy.isreal returns True for a dict ??

The logic of this eludes me and makes the isrealobj function not very usable (for my application). Is this a bug (and should it be reported) ?

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.9 (default, Aug 14 2018, 21:28:57) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.10.4'
>>> numpy.isrealobj('a string')
True
>>> numpy.iscomplexobj('1+1j')
False
>>> numpy.isrealobj(False)
True
>>> numpy.iscomplexobj(False)
False
>>> numpy.isreal('1.0')
False
>>> numpy.isreal(True)
True
>>> numpy.isreal({'a':'1','b':1})
True
```

Comment: The docs are pretty explicit: "The type of the input is checked, not the value. So even if the input has an imaginary part equal to zero, isrealobj evaluates to False if the data type is complex."

Comment: ok. but why is a dict or a string a real object ?

Comment: Please read the docs: "Return True if x is a not complex type or an array of complex numbers." https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.isrealobj.html a dict is not a complex type, so True is returned

Comment: It with `iscomplexobj` only checks the `dtype`.  Don't try to apply it to strings or scalars.  It's a test for numeric arrays.

Comment: What's your application?

Comment: I have is function that depending on whether you feed it a function, a real or a string does something with it ... The function path is selected through hasattr __call__ , the string bit through isinstance str and I wanted to select for real objects. The information of what was supplied is stored and used much later in the program.

Comment: after reading the docs I'm thinking that the name of isrealobj should really have been isnotcomplexobj and in any case the isreal of a dict or boolean should have returned a False even according it's documentation; but heck what do I know ...

Comment: The documentation has a link to the `[source]`.  What's your definition of `real`?  Remember this is `numpy`,  ot general python.

Comment: I was expecting as definition of real anything what numpy can understand as a real (so the various precisions and  int (various sizes)); I was definitely not expecting dict, boolean and/or str. Ok: it is what it is but it is confusing if one does not want to go back the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.isrealobj??` in IPython (or the `[source]` link online):

```
def isrealobj(x):
    """
    Return True if x is a not complex type or an array of complex numbers.
    ...
    See Also
    --------
    iscomplexobj, isreal
    ...

    """
    return not iscomplexobj(x)
```

That first line is a reasonable summary of the code, especially if you don't read too much into it.  The `See Also` note also points in this direction.  Both this and `iscomplexobj` say they check `type`, not `value`, with a special note about `an imaginary part equal to zero`.

The code for `iscomplexobj` is:

```
    try:
        dtype = x.dtype
        type_ = dtype.type
    except AttributeError:
        type_ = asarray(x).dtype.type
    return issubclass(type_, _nx.complexfloating)
```

It checks the `dtype` of `x`, or the `dtype` `np.asarray(x)` if `x` isn't already a `ndarray`.

```
In [113]: np.array('1+1j').dtype
Out[113]: dtype('<U4')
In [114]: np.array({}).dtype
Out[114]: dtype('O')
In [115]: np.array(1.23).dtype
Out[115]: dtype('float64')
In [116]: np.array(1.23+0j).dtype
Out[116]: dtype('complex128')
```

`isinstance` checks the `__mro__` stack

```
In [117]: np.float64.__mro__
Out[117]: 
(numpy.float64,
 numpy.floating,
 numpy.inexact,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 float,
 object)
In [118]: np.complex128.__mro__
Out[118]: 
(numpy.complex128,
 numpy.complexfloating,
 numpy.inexact,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 complex,
 object)
```

This sort of logic applies to all the `is_type` functions listed here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/routines.logic.html#array-type-testing

When understanding a Python function, the code is king.  The documentation should be a good summary of that action, but usually can't capture all the nuances.  The name is at best a helpful mnemonic.  They all have to be understood in the context of Python and their package.

---

Testing for `function` with the `__call__` attribute makes sense, as does `isinstance` for `str`.

`real objects` is still a bit unclear.  I imagine `type(12)` and `type(12.3)` should test true.  How about `type(12+1j)`?  How about `numpy` arrays or objects of `numpy.ScalarType`?

A brief web search for "python test for number" took me to the `numbers.Number` test:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/numbers.html

```
In [134]: import numbers
In [135]: isinstance(12, numbers.Number)
Out[135]: True
In [136]: isinstance(12.23, numbers.Number)
Out[136]: True
In [137]: isinstance(12.23+1j, numbers.Number)
Out[137]: True
In [138]: isinstance('12.23+1j', numbers.Number)
Out[138]: False
In [139]: isinstance({}, numbers.Number)
Out[139]: False
In [140]: isinstance(np.float64(12), numbers.Number)
Out[140]: True
In [141]: isinstance(np.complex(12), numbers.Number)
Out[141]: True
```

Comment: I'll accept the answers given as well as the solution via the numbers module. Thx. Without wanting to debate the matter here I am puzzled why _isrealobj_ is not implemented similarly to _iscomplexobj_: it's not even faster as it requires the call to _iscomplexobj_ and the negation. Similarly for _isreal(x)_ which simply turns out to be _imag(x) == 0_.

Comment: @Frederic. How else would you check if a number was real?

Comment: not wanting to drag out the debate as well not sure if your question relates to _isreal_ or _isrealobj_: instead of using _isreal(x)_ one could use the expression _imag(x)==0_. For what concerns the _isrealobj_ I notice that _iscomplexobj_'s source indeed tests for the dtype _complexfloating_ (in _numpy.core.numeric_ but I could not find it there). The various type of numpy scalar numbers are also documented in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.scalars.html where the type _floating_ also appears: so _isrealobj_ could be implemented as _iscomplexobj_ is. (accurate/faster)

Comment: The only use I find in `numpy` for `isrealobj` is in testing that `np.poly` produces "real output for perfect conjugates", numpy/lib/tests/test_polynomial.py.  `iscomplexobj` is used in `np.savetxt`, `np.interp`, `np.corrcoef` and `ma.var` - calculations where complex arrays require special handling.  In other words, they are both utility functions, for use in specific numpy contexts, not general purpose Python tests.